# Bulk In/Out transfer through ncm gadget in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am using iMX6 Sabrelite rev-D board as device and x86 as host. I have added an extra interface in NCM gadget(g_ncm) for bulk in/out transfer by giving specific endpoints for bulk in and bulk out transfer. Host is able to complete the enumeration process. From the host side I am able to ping the device & vice-versa. I want my device to send/recv data to/from host respectively through the extra interface I  added in NCM gadget. I am not able to proceed further for data exchange b/w host and device. Any information would be massively appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please try to improve your spelling. Although high level English is not expected here, but you can get much better acceptance if you follow this [six simple spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh/291370#291370).

Comment: Thanku for the advice @peterh